# Calculate dataframe variable p-value

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, p-value

I use a logistic regression (glm function).

```
model <- glm(`Type de client` ~ `Age du client`,
          data = tdata,family = "binomial")

#List of z value
summary(model)$coef[,3]
```

First question what's the difference between z-value and p-value?

Result:

```
-1.2531062 
`Age du client`de 40 à  50 ans 
1.3773904 
`Age du client`moins de 23 ans 
-1.1222482 
`Age du client`plus de  50 ans
```

Second question how can I have the p-value of the variable `Age du client` and not only for his subsets?

Comment: try `anova(model,test="Chisq")`

Comment: Question 1) z values represent your test statistic for your coefficients and the p value for each represents the probability that you would have obtained each test statistic if the coefficient equaled 0 in the population. 2) Not knowing your data it is hard to say what you think should be presented regarding the variable `Age du client`, but one reason you may not be getting what you want is that R recognizes that variable differently from how you intend it to be used in the analysis (i.e., as a factor when you would like to use it continuously or vice versa).